# salesforce deployment from Git with Docker cloud

Tags: deployment, salesforcedx, version-control, github, dockercloud

I need way to deploy code from Git to salesforce using Docker Cloud or Docker. I needed senior's suggestions and sources on deployment from Git to to salesforce especially with [docker](https://www.docker.com/) and i found way to do it with BitBucket [here](https://www.cloudinit.nz/single-post/2016/11/25/Automated-Salesforce-Deployments-with-BitBucket-Pipelines) but didn't find with Git or at least is it possible at the current moment with docker?.

Comment: Wait a momento... git is a client and BitBucket is a repository... so what do you need specifically?

Comment: I need a deployment approach from Git Hub to Salesforce with Docker Cloud, The reason i typed Git and Hub separately is because my company internet policy , if it sees anything with Git+Hub it will block accessing and i cant even see this quetion then.

Comment: How is this different from your last [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/234902/deployment-with-docker-cloud-or-kubernates-for-salesforce)? There are tons of resources available for how to perform deployments out of Git, and Git Hub and BitBucket both offer more or less equivalent Git hosting.

Comment: It's not clear to me what role you are envisioning for Docker in this process.